# Keras backend (tensorflow) vs tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-functions, tensorflow, keras

I do not really understand the difference between Keras backend (when you use tensorflow as backend) and tensorflow.
I saw some posts where people were trying to modify a Keras loss function and to do so, they were using `keras.backend` functions.

Is it possible to use directly functions from tensorflow ? Because on tensorflow, there are many more function available than on `keras.backend`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, Keras is easier to use. See this post on Medium: [TensorFlow or Keras? Which one should I learn?](https://medium.com/implodinggradients/tensorflow-or-keras-which-one-should-i-learn-5dd7fa3f9ca0).

Simplicity comes at the cost of flexibility, but allows faster implementation for prototyping.